# Is this is a Javascript's substring bug or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript

This is a screenshot from my Chrome browser console window (running in Chromes OS 72.0.3626.97).

substring(0,1) works as expected, but (1,1) does not, whereas .charAt() consistently produces the expected result and, as shown, is not in sync with substring after the (0).

[image: console screen shot]

Comment: You did not find a bug.  Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).  The second argument is *not* the length of the string to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no character between indexes `1` and `1` in the string.

Comment: @AlanM. See also [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) _"Matches a word boundary. This is the position where a word character is not followed or preceded by another word-character, such as between a letter and a space. Note that a matched word boundary is not included in the match. In other words, the length of a matched word boundary is zero."_ `test.match(/\b/g)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel like such an idiot. I've used it for years, and just went stupid.